# Is "Next to that" really an alternative to "Additionally" or "Moreover"?

Tags: phrases, word-usage, conjunctions

I see many of my compatriots using the phrase "Next to that" at the start of a sentence to mean "Additionally", "Moreover", "Furthermore" or "In addition".

The reason for this, I feel, may be that the Dutch word "daarnaast" (literally: "there" + "next to" / "beside") can be used both as a conjunction referring to physical proximity and as a member of the "Additionally" family of words.

I believe this particular use of "next to" in English to be incorrect or at least uncommon, but I haven't found a good source to back up this opinion. Could someone enlighten me here?

Comment: Your suspicions are right. It's common for people to translate expressions from their native tongues word-for-word, but a native English speaker wouldn't say that. It's incorrect.

Comment: I don't think it's impossible to use "next to that" to mean "in addition to that"; most people would intuitively understand what it meant. But it's an odd, foreign-sounding locution anyway, and might be confused with "besides."

Comment: i'd use that phrase in the sense of **but** or **besides that**.  e.g. "next to that, nothing really happened."

Answer (score 11):

Your instincts are correct: "next to that" is not something a native speaker would use if they wanted to say "additionally". Given enough context, most native speakers would understand what was meant, mind you, but like Robusto said, it's an odd, foreign-sounding locution. (Also, it might be misinterpreted as an attempt to say "besides".)

The phrase can be used literally, i.e. when talking about physical proximity, or it can be used with a sense of comparison, as in Jay's "Next to that, the $1 million ... is a minor problem". But just like none of those usages would work if you substituted "additionally", you can't really use "next to that" when you mean "furthermore".

Comment: Am I wrong to conclude that your and Jay's first paragraphs contradict each other?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: nope, you're 100% correct. I posted an answer because I disagreed with Jay's answer.

Comment: I'm confused that you say it might be *misinterpreted* as meaning "besides". Doesn't "besides that" essentially mean the same thing as "additionally", "moreover", etc?

Comment: @sumelic: "Besides" implies that the following clause is in some sense in opposition to the preceding statements. "Additionally", "moreover", etc. don't carry any such sense of opposition.

Comment: No, that's just wrong. "Besides" is often used to introduce a secondary argument that is independent of a preceding point but not in opposition to it.

Answer (score 2):

It's not wrong in English. You might say, for example, "Bob owns a car and a motorcycle. Next to that he also owns a boat."

In a similar way we also say "in addition to that" and "besides that".

"Next to that" can also be used literally, to mean that something is physically adjacent. Like, "On the desk is a pencil. Next to that is a pen." The pen is adjacent to the pencil.

"Next to that" is also used to make comparisons. Like, "The company lost $10 million on the failed product roll out. Next to that, the $1 million that we lost when the factory burned down is a minor problem."

Comment: Am I wrong to conclude that your and Martha's first paragraphs contradict each other?

Comment: Yes, we disagree. I think we should fight to the death.

Comment: Next to a mud fight, they could try a swordfight.

Comment: @jay could you point me to some online sources that actually use "next to that" in the way you describe it in your first sentence? I haven't found anything at all, at least not from native speakers/writers.

Comment: Search on "next to that" and most of the hits are talking about being physically adjacent, but I did find: http://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-25364745 and http://quotes.dictionary.com/For_as_the_interposition_of_a_rivulet_however

Comment: Your first citation is a direct quote from a Belgian MP who was interviewed in English. I'd say that only confirms my point that it is an error made particularly by Dutch speaking people.

Comment: In the Aristotle quote I believe "next to that" is used in a ranking sense, which seems to be related to your third type of use, not the first one, the one I contest.